# LWJGL 3 HelloWorld example crashing

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl3

I'm trying to start LWJGL 3 development and I am having an issue with getting things working. I have created a new Gradle project and successfully built the HelloWorld example from https://www.lwjgl.org/guide but when I run I get an error. However the error seems to be different each time. Here is one example:

```
Hello LWJGL 3.2.3 build 13!
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff6d4fe829, pid=4595, tid=5891
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (14.0.1+7) (build 14.0.1+7)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x6829]  objc_msgSend+0x29
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/rob/Projects/Personal/cc/hs_err_pid4595.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Another:

```
Hello LWJGL 3.2.3 build 13!
[thread 9731 also had an error]
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff34cc1027, pid=4579, tid=775
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (14.0.1+7) (build 14.0.1+7)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [CoreGraphics+0x73027]  CGClipRelease+0xe
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/rob/Projects/Personal/cc/hs_err_pid4579.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

What should I start looking at to resolve this?

Comment: Is there any more information in Users/rob/Projects/Personal/cc/hs_err_pid[number].log?

Comment: And just to confirm, you have passed "-XstartOnFirstThread" as a VM option?`

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Yes, I am running with `GRADLE_OPTS=-XstartOnFirstThread ./gradlew run`

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 However checking the log it doesn't seem the arg is being passed to the JVM

Comment: Thank you @Tyyppi_77 - it was indeed the missing start option. I added a run config to build.gradle and it now works. Would you like to post a full answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Done, would you mind editing my answer a bit to elaborate the final step of what to do with the Gradle build file, as I have no experience with Gradle itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the crash is inconsistent, it's probably a threading issue. The link you shared says

> MacOS users should start their application passing "-XstartOnFirstThread" as a VM option.

so I'm guess that you're not properly setting the VM option. Setup a run configuration in build.gradle.

Example run config for Gradle:

**Add to build.gradle**

```
run {
  if(project.hasProperty('arg')){
    args(arg.split(','))
  }
  main = "MyPackage.MyEntry"
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  jvmArgs = [
    "-XstartOnFirstThread"
  ]
  systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```